# jquery, phonegap: unsorted List overlay overlapps content of list

Tags: jquery, ios, list, mobile, cordova

I am developping a phonegap application with the help of jquery mobile. It has an unsorted list which works correctly under android but doesn't display the content correctly under ios.

The List looks like this in my html file:
`<ul id="bookingList" data-role="listview"></ul>`

and is populated with jscript:

`$('#mainList').append( "<li data-role='list-divider'>" + mainListNumber + "Nr." + endTag + mainListSwappingPreference + "T" + endTag + mainListName + "Name" + endTag + mainListReadyStatus + "Status" + endTag + mainListLastActionDate + "Datum" + endTag + "</li>");`

`for ( var object in mainList) {`

`$('#mainList').append("<li>" + mainListNumber + mainList[object].mainListNumber    + endTag + mainListSwappingPreference + mainList[object].swappingPreference + endTag + mainListName + mainList[object].firstname + " " + mainList[object].surname + endTag + mainListReadyStatus + mainList[object].readyStatus + endTag + mainListLastActionDate + dateFormat(mainList[object].lastActionDate, false) + endTag + "</li>");`

`}`

So there are two basic appends.

Styled with following css:

`#bookingTitles {
    font-size: 20pt !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}`

`#bookingStartDate {
    float: left;
    width: 85pt;
    margin-left: 1pt;
}`

`#bookingLoc {
    float: left;
    width: 65pt;
    margin-left: 10pt;
}`

Any idea why the layout is broken on ios?
Thanks in advance.

Screenshots:
Android:

[image: Android]

IOS:

[image: IOS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about my css overwriding the jquery styles for the listview and of course the error lies there:

`.ui-li-divider,.ui-li-static {

padding: 1pt !important;

}`

Doing this the height of the overlay does not match the height of the text anymore. The corrent version is:

`.ui-li-divider,.ui-li-static {

    padding-left: 1pt !important;

    padding-right: 1pt !important;
}`

Stupid mistake. Thx everyone for looking.